# Two Apps on iPhone vs the Same Apps on Android: Runkeeper and LibriVox and Playing Well Together

Tags: iphone, ios, notifications, settings

I recently switched from an Android phone to an iPhone SE, 3rd gen, running iOS 16.6, and I installed many of the same apps that I had on my Android. Two of those apps are Runkeeper and LibriVox. I like to listen to books on audio while I'm running, so I have Runkeeper announce progress and pacing and so on, while most of the time I'm listening to my book.

Now on Android, this worked precisely how I want: when the Runkeeper app had an announcement, the LibriVox book would pause, wait for the Runkeeper announcement to finish, *and then resume automatically.* For some reason, this is not the default behavior on iPhone. What happens is that LibriVox pauses when the Runkeeper announcement comes in, but never resumes unless I manually restart it. This is highly undesirable behavior.

I've seen some solutions online that involve turning off all notifications, but that won't work for me because I do want to have the Runkeeper notifications coming in. I want those announcements, I just want my book to resume again immediately when the annoucement is finished without me having to fingerprint in to the phone and re-start it manually while running.

LibriVox is unfortunately not one of the "Music" apps you can configure inside Runkeeper. I have looked inside both Runkeeper and LibriVox for settings to change this, to no avail. So my question is this: is there an iOS setting somewhere that will change this behavior so I can get it to behave like Android?

Perhaps more fundamentally: is this an iOS thing, a Runkeeper thing, or a LibriVox thing?

Comment: "ducking" what is playing under a notification is pretty standard on an iOS device and every app I have ever used does this when a notification (Phone call, text, etc...) pops up. As long as the app has notifications turned on that should just work. If it is not (as it seems to be not working) I would contact the developer(s). It might be a bug?

Comment: Thanks for the reply: when you write "As long as the app has notifications turned on ..." which app do you mean? As it turns out, I do have notifications for Runkeeper on, but LibriVox does not have an entry for notifications in the iOS Settings page. I have contacted the developers of both Runkeeper and LibriVox. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exciting development! I don't know whether LibroVox pushed out an update, or RunKeeper did. But I know that I upgraded from iOS 16.6.1 to iOS 17, and the problem appears to be completely fixed. Ducking happens just like in Android, whether the screen is black or LibriVox is on the lock screen, or whether I'm all the way into the main screen. Haven't tested it yet with RunKeeper having the focus, but as far as I'm concerned, this is good enough.